# I’m looking for a word that means sad singing

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Ive heard the phrase singing a sad tune, but I was wondering if there are any for suitable alternatives to singing. Ive thought of crooning, but that doesn’t sound right...

“It kinda sounds like I’m ____ a sad tune.”

Comment: Being that words are made up every day, I might suggest "I'm dirging a sad tune"

Comment: 1826   T. Hood She is far from Land in Whims & Oddities 76   Waves oversurging her, Syrens a-dirgeing her.

Comment: This may works for you : https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282227/the-term-for-singing-in-a-very-sad-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I saw your sample sentence, I was going to give you

**lament**

which is a sad song, and a bit old-fashioned.  But after reading your sample sentence, I can offer several synonyms for the verb *to sing* that some degree of sadness might fit better into:

- intone
- whine
- yodel
- belt
- moan

But my intuition tells me what you're really looking for is a slightly different sentence:

> It kind sounds like I'm s**inging the blues** today.

That is a modern way of expressing exactly what I think you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out that the song would likely be a  melancholic dirge similar to those chanted at a funeral. They may include sonic techniques such as [“appoggiatura”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appoggiatura) frequently used in songs popularised by Adele.

Aappoggiatura are one form of "discord" and we may often describe those sounds as ["discordant"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discordant)

Other than **`chanting`** or possibly **`dirge-ing`** it would be difficult to use those words in the context of

> “It kinda sounds like I’m ____ a sad tune.”

However I am going to plump for a common (but almost certainly incorrect) term

> “It kinda sounds like I’m **droning** a sad tune.”

[Droning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone_(music)) is probably in reality the opposite of the emotive inflections that are are being used by the singer.However we are often left with that feeling the tone was downbeat.

On a light-hearted note :-) Sad fans may be found droning their sorrows after their match.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe humming, belting out, or harmonizing?